# Python + django list + HTML select option

Tags: python, sql-server

Bom dia galera,

Preciso da ajuda de vocês quanto a um código que estou desenvolvendo em python + django

Eis meu problema: tenho uma função na views.py na qual realiza um select de Nome na tabela de clientes e coloca os dados(fetchall()) dentro de uma lista, e manda esta lista via template para a página HTML de exibição.

Na página de HTML, recebo a lista via template e para cada linha da lista, exibo um option com o valor da linha em value e no próprio nome de visualização do option

Porém, ao invés de aparecer somente o nome do cliente 
Cliente 
Aparece cheio de sujeiras da lista
('Cliente', )

Já tentei fazer replace ao receber, porém deixa de ser uma lista e exibe tudo numa linha só
Já tentei enviar de forma dinâmica vários templates, porém nao tem como recebe-los dinamicamente também no HTML

Se vocês puderem me dar alguma ideia que possa resolver esse meu problema, ficarei muito grato.

Comment: Dessa forma fica dificil te ajudar, o ideal é que voce coloque fragmentos do seu codigo e aponte onde está, especificamente o problema. Voce conhece o contexto, os que lêem a pergunta não.

Comment: Adicione o código que você está usando para vermos qual o problema..

Comment: Sobre essa parte: 1 - "Porém, ao invés de aparecer somente o nome do cliente Cliente Aparece cheio de **sujeiras** da lista ('Cliente', )" 2 - O que seria esse resultado? 3 - Essa lista de clientes como é que esta buscando essa informação? Gostaria de ajudar se pudesse esclarecer essas partes.

Comment: epecifique o valor do campo que voce quer visualizar ex: {{cliente.nome}}